# Is it true that a processor with a higher temperature uses inevitably more power in comparison with a processor with a lower temperature?

Tags: energy, electric-circuits, temperature, power, computer

If a processor has a higher temperature, can you be sure it it consumes more power than a processor with a lower temperature?

And is the reverse relationship true?
A processorchip with a higher mean power consumption will always work at a higher temperature than a processer with a lower mean power consumption?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No.  Power and temperature are related, but not directly.  Thermal environment and surface area also matter a great deal.

A tiny chip has less area to dissipate heat than a larger one.  So for the same power draw, it may easily produce a higher temperature than a larger chip.

Imagine a 40W incandescent light bulb.  Both the filament and the bulb as a whole are dissipating 40W of power.  But the tiny filament can do so only by climbing to a very high temperature of a few thousand $K$.  The larger bulb surface dissipates the same amount at a few hundred $K$.

Design affect things as well.  If you have a chip that happens to be quite robust at high temperature, you might allow it to reach high temperatures in your product.  But a more powerful one might need aggressive cooling, which keeps it at a lower temperature.